# Disassemble raw x64 machine code

Tags: 64-bit, objdump, disassembly

What is the right architecture to get objdump to disassemble raw x64 code? You would think `-m x86-64` should work from reading the help, but it doesn't. I tried with both the cygwin64 version:

```
$ objdump --version
GNU objdump (GNU Binutils) 2.23.52.20130604
```

as well as the version in my Fedora 18 x64 install (`2.23.51.0.1-3.fc18 20120806`) but I only get `can't use supplied machine x86-64`. Also tried with `amd64` and `x64` but that didn't work either.

The command is basically `objdump -b binary -D -m ??? file`

Answer (score 25, accepted):

And as usual writing down the question already gives you some rather good ideas what else to try..

Anyhow the right machine architecture is: `i386:x86-64`.

The full command is:

```
objdump -b binary -D -m i386:x86-64 <file>
```

If you want to disassemble code that expects to be loaded at a specific address, you can add the `--adjust-vma <load-address>` flag.

Answer (score -1):

Many years has past and now it works as such:

```
$ objdump -b elf64-x86-64  -M "intel" -d 27.exe
```

The field "-b" can be determined with the help of objdump:

```
$ objdump -f 27.exe

27.exe:     file format elf64-x86-64
```

Answer (score -2):

using **objdump from gcc** as shown below.

```
objdump -z -M intel -d test.o
```